# Can't create table (ERROR 1215) even with SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, ddl, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

What I am trying to do I've done countless times but now fails having upgraded from MySql 5.6.26 to 5.6.27 (also fails in 5.7.x).  I have a database with a bunch of tables with foreign key constraints.  I have exported (using phpMyAdmin) replacements tables specifying the following export options:

```
Disable foreign key checks
Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER statement
Add CREATE TABLE statement
```

The resulting export file contains in part:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `application`;
CREATE TABLE `application` (
  `PK_Application` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplicationLevel` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Sequence` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

. . .
. . .

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product_x_application`;
CREATE TABLE `product_x_application` (
  `PK_Product_X_Application` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Product_PKID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Application` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

. . .
. . .

ALTER TABLE `product_x_application`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_x_application_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Application`) REFERENCES `application` (`PK_Application`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

When this file is input to either mysql.exe or the phpMyAdmin import function when tables `application` and `product_x_application` already exist, the DROP statement for table `application` succeeds but the subsequent CREATE TABLE statement fails with:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

If, however, I first drop the `product_x_application` table, which has a foreign key constraint `product_x_application_ibfk_2` that references table `application`, then the CREATE TABLE statement succeeds.

I have since learned more info.  I went up to my production machine, which is running Linux with a MySql 5.5 server and phpMyAdmin 4.4.23 phpMyAdmin, and did an export of just the two tables in question and was able to import the resulting file into my MySql 5.6.27 server.  Here are the two *complete* export files (structure only).  First from the problematic 5.6.27 server:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.15
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jan 10, 2016 at 07:01 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.26-log
-- PHP Version: 5.6.12

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `spmorell_sami`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `application`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `application`;
CREATE TABLE `application` (
  `PK_Application` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplicationLevel` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Sequence` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `product_x_application`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product_x_application`;
CREATE TABLE `product_x_application` (
  `PK_Product_X_Application` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Product_PKID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Application` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `application`
--
ALTER TABLE `application`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Application`);

--
-- Indexes for table `product_x_application`
--
ALTER TABLE `product_x_application`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Product_X_Application`),
  ADD KEY `Product_PKID` (`Product_PKID`),
  ADD KEY `FK_Application` (`FK_Application`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `application`
--
ALTER TABLE `application`
  MODIFY `PK_Application` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `product_x_application`
--
ALTER TABLE `product_x_application`
  MODIFY `PK_Product_X_Application` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `product_x_application`
--
ALTER TABLE `product_x_application`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_x_application_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Product_PKID`) REFERENCES `product` (`Product_PKID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_x_application_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Application`) REFERENCES `application` (`PK_Application`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Notice that the primary key for the `application` table is defined in an ALTER TABLE statement.  Here is the exported file form the 5.5 server:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.8.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jan 10, 2016 at 05:09 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.42-37.1-log
-- PHP Version: 5.4.23

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `spmorell_sami`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `application`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `application`;
CREATE TABLE `application` (
  `PK_Application` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FK_Parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplicationLevel` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Sequence` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Application`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `product_x_application`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product_x_application`;
CREATE TABLE `product_x_application` (
  `PK_Product_X_Application` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Product_PKID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Application` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Product_X_Application`),
  KEY `Product_PKID` (`Product_PKID`),
  KEY `FK_Application` (`FK_Application`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1633 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `product_x_application`
--
ALTER TABLE `product_x_application`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_x_application_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Application`) REFERENCES `application` (`PK_Application`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_x_application_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Product_PKID`) REFERENCES `product` (`Product_PKID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Here the primary key for the `application` table is defined immediately when the table is defined.  I believe the problem is that the `product_x_application` table, which already exists when the system is attempting to re-create the `application` table, has a foreign key constraint to a table that when re-created does not have the required index on the foreign key because the primary key has not yet been defined.

Comment: Disable foreign key checks apply to inserts, updates, and deletes, not on creating or modifying tables.

Comment: if I try to drop table `application` I get ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails, but if I have SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;, then I can do teh drop.  So FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS has something to do with table creation and dropping. The problem is I have a database of N tables. A subset M of these is generated externally and I need to replace the M existing tables on the database with these tables.  I suspect that I can do so by explicitly first setting FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 and dropping the M tables before doing the import, but oh what a pain!

Comment: When you drop a parent table that has records that are being referenced by a foreign key, then removing the parent records is a violation of the foreign key. So, it has nothing to do with drop table. Just think through the side efcects of dropping a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have *even more* info.  I had installed a later version of phpMyAdmin (4.5.0.2) but forgot all about it.  For giggles I decided to do the export with that.  As before, I specified as options ADD DROP TABLE (ADD CREATE TABLE is automatically checked and cannot be unchecked).  But now, next to the IF NOT EXISTS sub-option for ADD CREATE TABLE it says in parentheses, "(less efficient as indexes will be generated during table creation)", which of course is precisely what I need (normally I would not think of checking this option because I know the table can't possibly exist at this point).  And the output is:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.0.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jan 10, 2016 at 07:54 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.26-log
-- PHP Version: 5.6.12

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `spmorell_sami`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `application`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `application`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `application` (
  `PK_Application` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FK_Parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplicationLevel` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Sequence` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Application`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `product_x_application`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product_x_application`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_x_application` (
  `PK_Product_X_Application` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Product_PKID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Application` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Product_X_Application`),
  KEY `Product_PKID` (`Product_PKID`),
  KEY `FK_Application` (`FK_Application`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1633 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `product_x_application`
--
ALTER TABLE `product_x_application`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_x_application_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Product_PKID`) REFERENCES `product` (`Product_PKID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_x_application_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Application`) REFERENCES `application` (`PK_Application`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

So the problem all along was the phpMyadmin 4.4.15 release and not the MySql release. Clearly I had been periodically upgrading phpMyAdmin releases and I can infer that I never had the occasion to run the import with the problematic (at least for me) phpMyAdmin release 4.4.15 until now.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key should reference a unique column (e.g., a primary key). `PK_Application`, currently, is not such a column. From its name, though, it seems as though you meant for it to be a primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE `application` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `application_pk` PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Application`);
```

Comment: I specified that I was including the DDL "in part".  I omitted other DDL statements that specified the primary key for the `application  table` via an ALTER TABLE statment.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson why is the pk constraint defined in an alter table instead of in the create table?

Comment: That is the way phpMyAdmin and/or MySql generates the output file when you do the phpMyAdmin export operation (it is not the way I originally defined the table).  I can't be sure whether the behavior is a function of phpMyAdmin or MySql.

Comment: @Mureinik See my answer: The primary key is being defined, albeit in the ALTER TABLE statement, and that is a peculiarity of the particular release of phpMyAdmin and it was the cause of all my woes.